# Symfony2 Override part of template from third-party bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I am using SonataAdminBundle for my project and I would like to override a block.

If I create a template in `app/Resources/views/SonataAdminBundle/views/standard_layout.html.twig` clear the cache and do this:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block theBlockIWantToOverride %}
{% endblock %}
```

I get a `Maximum function nesting level of '250' reached, aborting!` error.

If I remove the `extends` part it renders a blank page. Instead, I have to copy the entire file contents to this new file and then change the block content. I know this is how Symfony2 works, I just don't know if there is a workaround without having all the code there?

The reason I want to do this is because I use SensioLabsInsight and it's been bugging me about the `raw` twig filter that SonataAdminBundle uses. I know I can just ignore the warning but it feels wrong.

Also, I tried to override the bundle by creating a bundle `php app/console generate:bundle` and then in src/Vendor/AdminBundle/VendorAdminBundle.php I added:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'SonataAdminBundle';
}
```

and done the above process, added a `src/Vendor/AdminBundle/Vendor/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig` which didn't solve the issue. Again, got the nesting level error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template at `app/Resources/views/SonataAdminBundle/views/standard_layout.html.twig` is extending `SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig` which is the same file, meaning that it is just extending itself until it dies.

You should copy the contents of the file and change what you need to in that.

Alternatively you could copy the original `standard_layout.html.twig` and rename it (to `standard_base.html.twig` for example), then override your blocks in your version of `standard_layout.html.twig` and then extend your `standard_base.html.twig`.

Even more alternatively, and better for SonataAdminBundle, you can use a different named template (`VendorAdminBundle::standard_layout_override.html.twig` for example) as your version of the `standard_template.html.twig` to extend the original and set it in the config like...

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  VendorAdminBundle::standard_layout_override.html.twig
```

Comment: it works! I don't know how I didn't thought of that! Thanks for helping me move on with this!

Answer (score 1):

**With the way you're trying :**

1. You have to copy the content of the original file
2. Paste the content in `app/Resources/views/SonataAdminBundle/views/standard_layout.html.twig`
3. Override[|modify] the block you want
4. Don't need to add `{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}`

**With the doc** : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html

Extract :

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
        history: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history.html.twig
        preview: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:preview.html.twig
        delete:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:delete.html.twig
        batch:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__batch.html.twig
        acl:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:acl.html.twig
        action:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:action.html.twig
        select:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__select.html.twig
        filter:  SonataAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        dashboard:           SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
        search:              SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        batch_confirmation:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:batch_confirmation.html.twig
```

Comment: Actual doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/templates.html